# Using "USER_PASS" with datastudio connector

Tags: javascript, looker-studio

I am having a bit of trouble setting up the "USER_PASS" type of authentication for my datastudio connector, and have had a hard time finding adequate examples (the official documentation offers but a partial picture). Has anyone set this up before, and could you please share with me how you had to configure it? If anyone has a link to an example that would be a great help, thanks!

Comment: The main issue that I am having is that once I submit the authentication, the code is working(based on logs), but I still get a "I'm sorry we failed to submit your credentials due an to unknown error" message. Has anyone else experienced this? The same happens with KEY authentication.

Comment: This [kaggle connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/kaggle/src/connector.js) user `USER_PASS`. Does that help?

Answer (score 10):

Oh how I know and share the pain of finding adequate examples.. The [kaggle connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/kaggle/src/connector.js) mentioned by @diminishedprime actually is using what I found to be working, too. Here is an abridged example which I hope is helpful for you.

---

Basically you will need a combination of things. The first would be to implement [getAuthType()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getauthtype) to tell the Data Studio that it might need to display such a mask:

```
function getAuthType() {      
  return {
    type: 'USER_PASS'
  };
};
```

---

Then, because you are using `USER_PASS`, the Data Studio invokes [isAuthValid()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#isauthvalid) and expects it to return a `Boolean`. Everytime you are on the first page of the configuration for the data source that uses your connector, this function is invoked. If it returns `false`, a mask like this will be displayed:

[image: Authenticate using <code>USER_PASS</code>]

But if it returns `true`, this step will be jumped over.

But what is the logic behind that, you might ask? I myself and the [kaggle connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/kaggle/src/connector.js) are using the [UserProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties()) to persist the username/password with which to use this data source. You can check if the right credentials are there and authenticate them via your REST endpoint and return your `Boolean` according to this. It might look something like this:

```
function isAuthValid() {
  const usernameAndPassword = loadUsernameAndPassword();
  return usernameAndPassword.username && usernameAndPassword.password && validateCredentials(usernameAndPassword.username, usernameAndPassword.password)
};
```

`loadCurrentUsernameAndPassword()` just loads them from the [UserProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties()):

```
function loadCurrentUsernameAndPassword() {
  const properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  return {
    username: properties.getProperty('dscc.username'),
    password: properties.getProperty('dscc.password')
  }
};
```

`validateCredentials()` is explained further down.

---

When the user types his username/password and clicks the *Send*-Button (I assume that's what it's called in english), the Data Studio then invokes [setCredentials()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#setcredentials), which you will need to implement.
You would probably need to call your REST endpoint, send the username/password and process the reply. It may look something like this:

```
function setCredentials(request) {
  var isCredentialsValid = validateCredentials(request.userPass.username, request.userPass.password);
  if (!isCredentialsValid) {
    return {
      errorCode: "INVALID_CREDENTIALS"
    };
  } else {
    storeUsernameAndPassword(request.userPass.username, request.userPass.password);
    return {
      errorCode: "NONE"
    };
  }
};
```

As you can see, I have introduced 2 new functions.

The first new function `validateCredentials()` actually sends the credentials to the REST endpoint, using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

```
function validateCredentials(username, password) {
  var rawResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('path/to/your/authentication/endpoint', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password)
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });

  return rawResponse.getResponseCode() === 200;
}
```

The second new function `storeUsernameAndPassword()` stores the username/passwort into the [UserProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties()):

```
function storeUsernameAndPassword(username, password) {
  PropertiesService
    .getUserProperties()
    .setProperty('dscc.username', username)
    .setProperty('dscc.password', password);
};
```

---

Now you have a valid username and password stored in the [UserProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties()) which you can send to your REST endpoint whenever the Data Studio invokes [getData()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getdata). For instance like this:

```
function getData(request) {
  const usernameAndPassword = loadUsernameAndPassword();

  var rawResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('path/to/your/data/endpoint?foo=bar', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(usernameAndPassword.username + ':' + usernameAndPassword.password)
    }
  });

  // transform your rawResponse ...
}
```

---

Now, there is an issue with this approach, which can't be resolved right now. The [UserProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties()) will not be cleared ever. So in theory, without hacking around, the username/password combination, once typed and validated by the user and stored into the UserProperties, are there forever. According to the Community Connector API Reference, we can implement [resetAuth()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#resetauth) where this information could be removed from the UserProperties, but it seems resetAuth() is currently never being invoked, ever. I already started a discussion about that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53189697/3628926).

---

It is also somewhat explained at https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth

Comment: Hero! Been looking for weeks, and this was the solution!