# Google Data Studio - When is resetAuth() being called?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am having troubles with the `resetAuth()` function. I implemented it roughly like [this example](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth#resetauth), but I have no idea when it is being called. Adding a console output and observing the Stackdriver Log tells me that this function is never being called during what I would call a normal workflow.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#resetauth) is weirdly brief and is missing this part about why I need to implement it and when it is being called. Do I need to call resetAuth() manually on some point? Is there a button somewhere that calls this function?

I'm using the [AuthType](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#authtype) `USER_PASS` by the way and everything else seems to work just fine after some investigation and debugging.

I found this document called [Community Connectors Developer Launch](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/developer-launch/) where, among other things, the following it listed (as of 2018-07-30):

> **What's next: Upcoming changes and improvements**
>
> Some of the features and improvements we'll be working on in the
>   coming months include:
>
> **Configuration and Authentication**
>
> - Capability to execute the `resetAuth` function of community connectors from within Data Studio.

Does this mean that calling `resetAuth()` is currently not yet implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resetAuth` is called when the user revokes access to the connector via the https://datastudio.google.com/datasources/create endpoint.

There was a bug that caused this function to not be called for certain auth types, but it has been resolved.